# jQuery Mouseover if statement inside of hover statement

Tags: jquery

Can someone please look at my code and tell me where I am going wrong?

```
$("div.inner").hover(function(){
    $("span.arrowL, span.arrowR").fadeIn("slow");
    if ($('div#move_next').mouseover()){
      return false; 
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  },
  function(){
    $("span.arrowL, span.arrowR").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

I am trying to get background images to fade in on a hover and if someone hovers over a certain area I want the arrows to stay there instead of fade out.

Comment: can you post the corresponding html and css so that we can test?

Comment: All the CSS can be found at http://jjordanweb.com

Comment: @jj why to have a if condition for mouseover , if someone mouseover it gets trigger otherwise not , I think there is no need to use if condition for mouseover

Comment: You'll notice that when you hover over the pictures on the secondary pages, arrows appear. When you move over to the arrow it triggers a horizontal scroll but the arrows disappear. I want the corresponding arrow to remain depending on the direction you are sliding.

Comment: @gov, there is a secondary div inside of the primary div that can also be hovered on and when that is hovered, I want the corresponding arrow to remain visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking that once hovering over the arrowL or arrowR elements the hover for the overall parent container is no more and the fade out is called.

Comment: So is what I'm asking not possible?

Comment: Ha, sorry, left you with bit of a vague answer there. I think its definitely possible just need to figure out the event arrangement. Mulling it over while football is on takes time :)

Comment: ideamachine's solution looks good. In digging through this, one minor issue with the script design is if users hover over the #move elements first the arrows will not be display and the scrolling will occur. If this is by design or not a big deal, I'll leave up to you. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#move_prev').mouseover(function() {
    $('span.arrowL').stop(true).css('opacity', 1);
});

$('#move_next').mouseover(function() {
    $('span.arrowR').stop(true).css('opacity', 1);
});
```

This should stop the fade-out from happening on the arrow the user's mouse pointer moves over and reverse that part of the fade-out has already been done. This is necessary because `#move_prev` and `#move_next` are not inside `div.inner`, so that's why the arrows hide.

Comment: This worked, thanks a million idealmachine. Any change I can get you to explain what is going on here logically.

So when one of the move divs is moused over it places a stop on any functions running on span and gives its css an opacity of 1? Is this close?

Comment: @JJ Nold: `.stop(true)` stops the currently running effect (on the *correct* arrow that the mouse pointer is over) and clears the queue of effects left to be run. http://api.jquery.com/stop/ Since the fade out would have already started, `.css('opacity', 1)` is necessary to make the arrow fully opaque again, all this because `#move_prev` and `#move_next` are not within `div.inner`.